# Restrict User from shopping again if any product is added to the Cart

Tags: magento, checkout, magento-1.5

Once a user has added a product to the Shopping Cart , I want to restrict that specific user from shopping further during the particular session.
If the user check out and visit again to the Website, he should be able to Shop again but the above rule must be considered.

Is this functionality available in Magento?Can anyone provide a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course this is possible! Configure an observer for the `controller_action_predispatch` event, grab the quote object from the session - if it contains items, set the redirect in your observer method and redirect them to the cart. Example (*not tested*):

```
public function restrictToCheckout(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getItemsCount();

    if ($items) {
        $observer->getControllerAction()->getResponse()
            ->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart'));

        Mage::throwException('You have items in your cart and must checkout'));
    }
}
```

There may be nuances, but this is the meat of it.

Comment: hi benmarks,Thanks a lot. But the actual problem is that, I just want to allow a particular user to shop only once i.e. When he added a product into his cart with a specific quantity, he must not be able to shop again. The only option for the user must be proceed to check out.